# VB NET AES encrypt

Tags: vb.net, encryption, aes

Can't reproduce an AES online encoder example using VB.Net

Trying in https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption with following parameters:

- Text to be Encrypted: test
- Cipher Mode: ECB
- Key Size: 128
- Secret Key: 1234567890123456

I get this output: **3fvaLg5IDlveswuXzhVQcw==**

If I try in VB.Net using this function (found in https://gist.github.com/ShaneGowland/5973974):

```
    Public Shared Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
        Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Dim encrypted As String = ""
        Try
            Dim hash(31) As Byte
            Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pass))
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
            AES.Key = hash
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB

            Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
            Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
            encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
            Return encrypted
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ex.ToString
        End Try
    End Function
```

I get this output: **6mhZOr1dQ7PWqbRGzmMgjg==** which is not matching with got at devglan.com

I tried with different paddings with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am aware that the ECB method should not be used

Comment: In the VB code there seems to be a key derivation via MD5 (unlike the web site). By the way, it is misleading to apply AES but name it **DES**Encrypter.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco , omitting that MD5 part is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with this function:

```
Public Shared Function AES_Encrypt(ByVal input As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim encrypted As String = ""
    Try
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        AES.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass)

        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input)
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return encrypted
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.ToString
    End Try
End Function
```